# Android UI design - Registration form with lots of parameters

Tags: android, user-interface

I have about 20 parameters needed for registration, please share your ideas on how to design a registration form, considering the number of parameters. Using a listview that contains all the parameters is not much user friendly.

Comment: Check this https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6cVymZvn3f4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally depends what are the widgets you have to use. And how much creative you can make the UI as per the user convenience. I have made an UI like this for more inputs from user. It is not possible to show it on one screenshots to but you can see. Contains more input fields. [![This is having more input fields][1]][1]

My code for this UI is..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
     >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_appointment_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        layout="@layout/layout_action_bar_header"
        android:background="@color/white" >
    </include>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/activity_appointment_header"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_appoinment_border"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_your_appointment_provider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/your_appointment_provider"
                    android:textColor="@color/cp_dark_blue_shade"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tr_book_doctor_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_book_doctor_photo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_placeholdar" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_book_doctor_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/not_found"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/size_title"
                            android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_book_hospital_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/not_found"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_book_address"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/not_found"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appointment_pref_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/appointment_preferences"
                android:textColor="@color/cp_dark_blue_shade"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_heading"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_select_pref_msg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/select_preferences_msg"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_appoinment_border"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_when_you_want_appointment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/when_do_you_want_appointment"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_no_preference"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                        android:text="@string/no_preference"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray" >
                    </Button>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_asap"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                        android:text="@string/asap"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray" >
                    </Button>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_one_week"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                        android:text="@string/in_one_week"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray" >
                    </Button>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_two_weeks"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                        android:text="@string/two_weeks"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray" >
                    </Button>
                </TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_what_day_of_week"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/what_day_of_week"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <com.mindbowser.choicehealthcare.views.MultiSelectionSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_day_of_week"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_what_time_of_day"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/what_time_of_day"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    layout="@layout/segmented_checkbox"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/time_day_anytime"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/time_day_morning"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/time_day_afternoon"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/time_day_evening"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_medical_emergancy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/medical_emergency_msg"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_order_to_process"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/provide_details"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_patient_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/patient_info"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/first_name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_last_name"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/last_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/date_of_birth" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_gender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_provide_contacts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/provide_contact_email"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_phone"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="phone" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_reason_of_visit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/reason_for_visit_star"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_reason_for_visit"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/reason_for_visit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_info_for_provider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/info_for_the_provider"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_info_for_provider"
                style="@style/editTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="250"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:singleLine="false" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/dark_default_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_payment_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/payment_details"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_pay_by_cash"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/paying_by_cash"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_pay_by_insurance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/paying_by_insurance"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_appointment_submitted"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_thank_you"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thank_you"
            android:textColor="@color/cp_red"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_appointment_request_sent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/appointment_request_sent"
            android:textColor="@color/cp_red"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_subtitle"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_provider_will_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/provider_will_contact"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_default_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_go_home"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_home" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_book_appointment_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/cp_red" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_book_appointment"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/book_now" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scroll view.
Under the scroll view,you can use either Linear layout or relative layout as parent view group.and manage all child layouts under that layout.